# ros2 and ignition roadmap

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the roadmap look like for ros2 x ignition? I see that ignition can be built from source for ros2, I also see that the demos directory of the [repo](https://github.com/osrf/ros2_ign/tree/master/ros2_ign_gazebo_demos) is a TODO. Is all the functionality I love in Gazebo with ros2 in ignition as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351734/ros2-and-ignition-roadmap/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2020-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What's the roadmap look like for ros2 x ignition?

- **Dashing**: You can compile [ros_ign](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign) from source, for either Blueprint or Citadel.
- **Eloquent**: `ros_ign` may compile from source but we're not testing it currently.
- **Foxy**: We'll release `ros_ign` with Citadel support into http://packages.ros.org shortly after Foxy's release

> Is all the functionality I love in Gazebo with ros2 in ignition as well?

Ignition and Gazebo have a different set of features, see the [feature comparison](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/comparison).

> I also see that the demos directory of the repo is a TODO

[Here](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/tree/dashing/ros_ign_gazebo_demos) are the Dashing demos.

#### Update

> will ignition and ROS2 have 1:1 mappings of versions?

As it's always been the case for several external dependencies, including Gazebo, the official version of Ignition for each ROS 2 distro will be defined in [REP-2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html) starting from [Foxy](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/217/files#diff-8621ab8ccd81e524939c76f402c88701R613) (Ignition Citadel ).

We've also always supported non-official Gazebo-ROS combinations through http://packages.osrfoundation.org/ , as documented on [Which combination of ROS/Gazebo versions to use](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros#UsingaspecificGazeboversionwithROS). We plan on keeping doing the same for Ignition.

> I’m not used to having the simulators be named vs version numbers.

For what it's worth, like ROS, we're choosing names alphabetically, so it should be easy to know version's relative ages.

> wondering if we should really be numbering both ignition and ROS2 versions alongside a name

Ignition is not a monolithic application like Gazebo, it's a collection of libraries. Each Ignition library has its own numbered version following semantic versioning. The named releases are just collections of major versions of each library that are guaranteed to work together. The same version of a library can be in multiple collections (i.e. `ign-math6` is used on both Blueprint and Citadel), but one collection can't have more than one version of each library. We think that, the same way as ROS distros, naming each collection makes it easier to talk about versions for various packages that are guaranteed to work together.

This is documented on [Ignition Releases](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/all/releases) and [Ignition Citadel libraries](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/install#citadel-libraries).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) with karma: 366 on 2020-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-05-08**:
Followup: will ignition and ROS2 have 1:1 mappings of versions? I’m not used to having the simulators be named vs version numbers. Its totally fair to have names and gets me wondering if we should really be numbering both ignition and ROS2 versions alongside a name.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) on 2020-05-08**:
Updated answer addressing your questions.